# How to display a image in a ListView in Delphi?

Tags: listview, delphi

I need to show a image from my database into listview component. I have tried something like this but unsuccessfully.

Example:

```
 var
   bmp: TBitmap;
   blob :TBLOBField;

 begin
         bmp := TBitmap.Create;

         blob := TBlobField.Create(nil);

        //get image from blob column 
        //image is type bmp
         blob := //here i set bmp image from db;

          bmp.Assign(blob);
          //ListView1 viewstyle is vsReport

          ListView1.LargeImages.Add(bmp,nil); //there is Runtime error access violation at address

 end;
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"there is error"* Can you say more. Compiler error? Runtime error? Many novice programmers think that error messages contain no useful information, and simply ignore their content. If you want to progress then can I suggest that you try to learn how to interpret error messages. Read them. Try to make sense of them. Once you start doing that you'll also realise that you must include the error message verbatim when asking questions about them.

Comment: Beyond that, please give us a [mcve]. Remove all the DB code, because presumably you know how to load an image from your DB. Instead provide complete code that attempts to display an image in your list view. The image could be created at runtime in some silly fashion, it should not matter what its content is. Then we'd know how your control is setup. What its `ViewStyle` is and so on.

Comment: Finally, you could use the example from the documentation. It can be found here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/ViewStyleProperty_(Delphi)

Comment: By the way, remember that your database must contain a Bitmap image, if it does contain a JPEG, PNG, ... then you would need additional code to convert it first to bitmap.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Runtime error access violation at address.. where i comment. My image is bitmap and i don't need icon in listview, i need large image. Style is vsReport

Comment: So you've decided that error messages can be useful at most partly, and decided to inform about the first half only. Whereas a read error close to zero might mean an unassigned image list for instance.

Comment: This is like pulling teeth. Just because you don't understand the error message does not mean that it contains no information. If you want to improve you will need to learn how to interpret error messages. This particular one is especially easy to understand. If only you would be able to learn how to do this you'd be able to solve more problems for yourself. Don't you want to be able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most plausible explanation for an access violation is that you did not assign anything to `LargeImages` and so it is `nil`. Drop an image list on to your form, and set the `LargeImages` to refer to that image list. That will resolve your access violation.

You will surely then discover that image lists require all images to have the same dimensions. This means that every image that you display in the list view must also have the same dimensions. You'll probably need to resize the raw images to match that common dimension, before you add to the image list.